# How can I display a pi symbol, properly laid out fractions etc. in the legend of a Matplotlib graph?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I used Matplotlib to draw a graph like so:

[image]

Currently, I create the legend for the graph with `plt.legend(['pi(x)', 'x / log(x)'])`, where `plt` comes from `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`.

How can I alter this so that the legend

- uses a proper π symbol (Greek letter pi);
- shows `x / log(x)` as a fraction (with `x` above a horizontal line, and `log(x)` below)?

Comment: The symbol for Pi is just a regular character (π). You can put that directly into any Python string.

Comment: Have you tried just writing `plt.legend(['π(x)', 'x / log(x)'])`?

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/text/mathtext.html

Comment: When asking a question about something like this, try to avoid requiring all sorts of imports and code that's unneeded to illustrate the problem. Most of the imports are not needed, and people will have an easier time to understand the problem and try a solution before posting if you provide a minimal, reproducible example.

Comment: " I want to give the term x/log(x) as a fraction" do you mean that you want the text on the axis to appear as fractions? Given the current values in the example, what would that look like? This is a separate question, but please be clear and explicit in what you need and what you've tried yourself. The answer is 'yes', but SO is not here to write your code for you, rather it's here to help you fix your own, or solve a hard problem.

Answer (score -1):

If you are used to that as a word-processor then you can use latex-style notation for the strings in the legend.

Note that you will almost certainly have to use raw strings (because of the number of \ signs, which look like escape characters). You might benefit from a larger font size.

```
plt.legend( [ r'$\pi(x)$', r'$\dfrac{x}{log(x)}$' ] )
```

The \dfrac version seems to work a bit better than just \frac, because the latter gets squashed down to an inline formula.

It gives something like

[image]

Comment: @Grismar, that’s unfair: my answer was actually uploaded first. That’s a pretty unfair statement.

Comment: You're right - sorry, I did not see yours before I saw @aries0152, but the timestamp is clear. If you make an edit to your answer - I can give it the appropriate upvote. You may want to point out that Pi could be represented as a UTF-character, but that LaTeX style code is required for the fraction, as indicated in the comments elsewhere.

Comment: Yes, that is true, but enough has been said by others about that now. Probably the only further change I would have made to my strings would have been to put “log” in an upright type, as befitting a function.

Answer (score -1):

You may include LaTeX style notation in the legend. Try changing the line of legend with -

```
plt.legend(['$\pi(x)$', '$\dfrac{x}{log(x)}$'])
```

Your full code should be something like this-

```
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import gmpy2
from grundfunktionen_working import *
import numpy as np

def pi(n):
    result = [None,]
    count = 0
    for h in range(1, n):
        if gmpy2.is_prime(h):
            count += 1
        result.append(count)
    return result

lim = 10**5

compare = [None,]
for h in range(2, lim+1):
    compare.append(h/math.log(h))


xachse = (list(range(lim // 5, lim+1, lim // 5)))
xachse.insert(0,1)
liste = pi(lim)
plt.plot(liste)
plt.plot(compare)
plt.xticks(xachse)
plt.legend(['$\pi(x)$', '$\dfrac{x}{log(x)}$']) # <--- change this line
plt.show()
exit()
```

I tried and got this image-
[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Note that OP technically doesn't "need to" use the LaTeX style notation, thanks to support for UTF-8 in matplotlib and the language, but it is good advice regardless since the solution will be applicable in older versions of Python, and perhaps on platforms that may not fully support UTF-8.

Comment: @Grismar LaTeX isn't needed to get the pi symbol (since it's a Unicode character), but it is needed to get a proper fraction (since that's a matter of text *layout*, not just what characters are used).

Comment: I agree with both comments. I slightly modified the answer.

Comment: Negative voter, care to explain, please?

Answer (score -3):

Edit as suggested by [Grisma](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4390160/grismar).

First of all, greek letters, among other non-ascii characters are treated just like ascii characters and therefore can be used as literal and identifier. Hence, both of the following are valid in python.

```
print("π")
π=1
```

Second, now regarding your questions: displaying greek letters and mathematical expressions in `matplotlib`: luckily matploblib's math-text may be helpful (a light weight TeX expression).

Therefore, according to the [official documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/text/mathtext.html), all greek letters can essentially be represented by placing `'$'`, not different from how you use LaTex.

For Pi, according to the [Symbol section](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/text/mathtext.html#symbols) it shall be `'$\pi$'`

```
fig = plt.figure()
fig.text(.2, .7, "$\pi$")
```

Regarding fraction, refer to this [section](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/text/mathtext.html#fractions-binomials-and-stacked-numbers):

```
fig = plt.figure()
fig.text(.2, .7 , r'$\frac{x}{log(x)}$')
```

The leading `r` indicates a raw string so you don't need to worry about the escapes.

Comment: Not only is the answer trivial and not needed, you're also going against the basic rule of [not posting code as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors).

Comment: @Grismar With all due respect I consider it as the showcase of how non-ascii characters are treated just as ascii characters (literal and identifier).

Comment: Both identifiers and strings in Python are UTF-8 by default, and have been since Python 3.0 ([more here](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html)) but since that's a very core feature of the language, the answer is trivial. It's also not a problem to illustrate an answer with an image (as the article I linked also says), but an answer or a question should never hide all of the core content in the image - which is what you're doing. Although still trivial, you could improve the answer by adding a code block that allows OP to copy and paste the example and try it in their environment.

Comment: @Grismar I see your point and I did find that OP actually wanted to know the answer to a much broader question. Appreciate the feedbacks. Updated the answer accordingly.